# How are the address of the memory and that of the register connected?(AddrConstant MIPS instruction)

Tags: mips, cpu-registers, cpu-architecture

In my computer organization course, I came across these basic MIPS instructions:

```
lw   $to, AddrConstant4($s1)  //&t0 = constant 4
add  $s3, $s3, St0            //$s3 = $s3 + $t0 ($t0 == 4)
```

My teacher said that `$s1` is a register address and the constant `4` is stored in memory.

Memory addresses and register addresses seem disconnected in my eyes.

I want to ask how does the computer get to the memory address from the register head address of `$s1`,
or how are the address of the memory and that of the register connected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lw $t, offset($s)` is encoded as

```
1000 11ss ssst tttt iiii iiii iiii iiii
```

Where `100011` is the opcode, `sssss` is the number of the base address register, `ttttt` is the number of the destination register, and `iiiiiiiiiiiiiiii` is an immediate signed offset.

In the case of `lw $t0, 4($s1)` that would be:

```
1000 1110 0010 1000 0000 0000 0000 0100
```

(`$s1` is register `$17`, i.e. 10001. `$t0` is register `$8`, i.e. 01000)

When the CPU encounters this instruction word it knows from the bit pattern that this is an `lw`, so it forms an effective address formed by the value of register number `sssss` + the immediate offset (sign-extended), loads a word from that address and stores the value in register number `ttttt`.

---

References:
[MIPS register table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253512%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
[MIPS instruction set reference](http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html)