# The meaning of AddrConstant4($s1) in MIPS

Tags: mips

I just started studying computer organization.

My question is similar to this article
[How are the address of the memory and that of the register connected?(AddrConstant MIPS instruction)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22114853/how-are-the-address-of-the-memory-and-that-of-the-register-connectedaddrconsta)

lw $t0, AddrConstant4($s1)

The meaning of this instruction is $t0=constant 4

How I understand this instruction is adding 4 to the value of register $s1 and, load (4+value of register $s1) into $t0.

My question is that I don't know what value does $s1 already have.

If $s1 has 0, it makes sense.

However, if $s1 has 5, $t0 will have 4+5=9.

who knows what value is in $s1.

or what I understood is wrong?

As soon as I wrote this question, another idea came to me.

AddrConstant4($s1) means put 4 into the value of register $s1. (It doesn't matter what value $s1 had before.)

So lw $t0, AddrConstant4($s1) is same as $t0==4.

This is right?

Comment: `lw $t0, AddrConstant4($s1)` presumably means that you're loading the constant 4 into `$t0` by having the value 4 stored somewhere in memory as a 32-bit value, and specifying the address of that value by adding some offset `AddrConstant4` to a base address held in `$s1`. Of course this would be pointless, since you could just use `ori $t0, $zero, 4` instead (or `li $t0, 4` if your assembler supports it).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please let me ask one more question. If there was another value(e.g. 17) in $s1, could I change the value 17 to 4 with using instruction "lw $t0, AddrConstant4($s1)" ???

Comment: `lw $t0, AddrConstant4($s1)` does not modify `$s1`. The destination register is `$t0`.

Comment: Then, what is going to happen if there were another value in $s1 like 17 ? What  I  understand frm "specifying the address of that value by adding some offset AddrConstant4 to a base address held in $s1. "  is putting AddrConstant4 into $s1. It means the change of value. Isn't it?

Comment: I'm not sure why you would use 17 as a base address(?). It seems like you might have misunderstood what the instruction does. What happens is that the constant `AddrConstant4` and the value in `$s1` are added together, and that sum is then used as an address to load a 32-bit value from memory.

Comment: What I want to mean is not  "17 == base address" but  "17 == the existing value of base address" (base address is $s1) . It's a bit difficult to understand "constant AddrConstant4 and the value in $s1 are added together" . If there was 17 as an existing value in $s1, the sum would not be 4. Right?

Comment: The value you're loading is not the value of `$s1`. It's a value located somewhere in memory, at the address given by `$s1 + AddrConstant4`. We have no way of knowing what that address will be just by looking at that instruction in isolation.

Comment: I think I understand more. But there is something still confused. The sum value(4+the value of $s1) is somewhere in memory. And I don't know the address.// fist step.// Is it right?

Comment: `4+the value of $s1` <-- You have no way of knowing that `AddrConstant4` will equal 4. It's pointless to look at this `lw` instruction in isolation and speculate about what the address will be at runtime or what will happen if you change the offset or base address. If you want to analyze the behavior of a particular instruction, do so in the context of a complete program.

Comment: As others are saying, there's not enough information to say much.  For example, there's no definition of `AddrConstant4`.  This could be a (data) label or it could be defined via `.eqv`.  No reason to assume that it has the value 4, b/c if we wanted to speak about what an instruction `lw $t0, 4($s1)` does, we would just say that instead of using the identifier.  If it is a data label, then this is a pseudo instruction that expands to multiple MIPS instructions.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir!! Now, I can understand it

Answer (score 0):

Its a pseudo instruction, that may expand to two or more instructions.

```
lw $t0, label($t1)
```

Expands to something like:

```
la $at, label
addu $at, $at, $t1
lw $t0, 0($at)
```

Where `la` itself is a pseudo instruction involving `lui` and perhaps `ori`.

There are some optimizations possible, but for the best code, much better to use `la` to load the label address into a register for a longer duration, e.g. that can be done outside a loop.  (OR change algorithm to use pointers.)